# How to search a unicode value in SQL Server passed in parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

I have a stored procedure which accepts an Unicode value as input and perform like operation on a table.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[CorrectionTmFiltered] 
(  
    @search nvarchar(40) 
)  
as  
    print @search 

    SELECT DISTINCT   
       trader_firms.tf_id, trader_firms.tf_title
    FROM       
       trader_firms 
    WHERE 
       tf_title like @search + '%'
```

But this query doesn't return any result.

Hard coded values used with `N` before value returns result.

Print statement gives "??"

The value I am passing is 'दि'

Comment: `foo like bar` is the equivalent of `foo=bar`. You need wildcards, e.g. `foo like '%bar%'` to be able to do substring matching.

Comment: yes i forgot to add them in code. i already have them. But still no luck.

Comment: Unicode function gives me the unicode number not the expression

Comment: My bad, use `NCHAR(UNICODE(@search))`

Comment: still not working getting ? as output of print statement.

Comment: How are you **calling** this stored procedure?

Comment: I don't think it's the cause of the problem, but just in case: `like @search + N'%'`. More importantly is how you call it, as it has already been pointed out.